# Call a function from inside another function using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I have a task to call function from another function based on user inputs. Please see the below snippet for better understanding of my requirement.

---

```
def main():

        Operation = raw_input(" \n Select the Operation  \n\n 1. CREATE \n 2. DELETE \n Enter: \n")
        Instance = raw_input(" \n Select the Instance \n\n 1. AsyncINT01 \n 2. AsyncOUT01 \n 3. Trans01 \n Enter: \n")
        if (Operation == '1'):
            Call create Function !!
        if (Operation == '2'):
            Call delete Function !! 



def create():

        if (Instance == '1'):
                Create Somemthiing !!
        if (Instance == '2'):
                Create Somemthiing !!

def delete():

        if (Instance == '1'):
                Delete Somemthiing !!
        if (Instance == '2'):
                Delete Somemthiing !!


def choice():

        Choice = raw_input(" \n Do you want to run the program again (yes/no) ? \n Enter: \n")
        if (Choice == "yes"):
            Call main Function !!
```

---

As described above, how do i achieve similar functionality ? 
After every operation (create/delete), I want to call the choice function every time.

Please help me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to read the most basic Python tutorial on how to call functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly basic and a simple starter's tutorial on python would answer this for you right away.

Regardless, take a look:

```
def some_func(argument):
    print('some_func called with ', argument)

def other_func():
    argument = input()
    some_func(argument)

other_func()
```

Functions are objects so you can call them as long as they are in the respective namespace.